# Fetch the Trace log path dynamically using Python or Shell script

Tags: python, shell, dynamicparameters

I have a use-case where I need to traverse into the path `/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/abc_def/abcdef/trace/` and fetch the trace logs.

Basically, the trace logs path is same but the values of the path vary from DB server to DB server.

For Oracle RBMS, let’s say the above said path will have `oracle` , and `rdbms/abc_def/abcdef` .

For the other DB, these words might vary.

Now, the main concern is - how can I derive this path dynamically (using Python or shell script whatever is possible) and then read the trace logs instead of hardcoding this path.

Could someone please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the values in advance you can use the following bash syntax:

```
ls /u01/app/oracle/diag/{oracle,postgres,mysql}/abc_def/abcdef/trace
```

If you don't know the values - you can just use a wildcard like so:

```
ls /u01/app/oracle/diag/*/abc_def/abcdef/trace
```